# What is selective disclosure?

Tags: investing

I was reading [This Ex-Microsoft Exec Will Not Sleep Until He Reinvents Investing](http://www.businessinsider.com/motif-investing-hardeep-walia-2012-6), and the article stated:

> ... Motif can't fix the problems of selective disclosure that gave
>   institutional investors a better grip on Facebook's prospects going
>   into the IPO...

What is selective disclosure, who provides it and how does it help institutional investors?

Comment: Motif Investing closed in May 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_disclosure) has this explanation:

> Selective disclosure is a situation when a publicly traded company
>   discloses material information to a single person, or a limited group
>   of people or investors, as opposed to disclosing the information to
>   all investors at the same time.
>
> Material information is roughly defined as information that would
>   cause a reasonable investor to make a buy or sell decision.

Thus, there may have been only some institutions given the information instead of everyone. In this case, I'd suspect that some of the institutional investors may have gotten more information than the public in terms of Facebook's data on some points though that is a guess.

To give an example of "Selective Disclosure" consider a reality competition show where the ending is taped months in advance of it being aired. In this case, some people may know the result though this isn't public knowledge. Thus, this information is selectively disclosed to people as some may know because they had technical roles in filming the ending, adding the music or editing the footage. Generally these people would be under non-disclosure agreements but they may tell their friends about which way they could bet in a way that gives them an unfair advantage and this is why ["Fair Disclosure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_Fair_Disclosure) was passed for public companies though prior to the IPO, Facebook is technically private.